# How to clear the internet explorer cache files for all users using cleanmgr.exe

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, vbscript

Am using the simple script to delete the Internet Explorer cache files for all users.

However the script is currently cleaning only for current user.

Is there anyway to clear the Internet Cache files for all user or any sample scripts which does the same?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps.

1.open notepad.

2.Write the code

`

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.shell")
objShell.run "cleanmgr"
Do While (objShell.AppActivate("Disk Cleanup : Drive Selection") = false )
   WScript.Sleep 3000
 Loop
objShell.AppActivate "Disk Cleanup : Drive Selection"
objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Do While (objShell.AppActivate("Disk Cleanup for OS (C:)") = false )
   WScript.Sleep 1000
 Loop
If objShell.AppActivate("Disk Cleanup for OS (C:)") = True Then
   objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
   objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
End If
Set objShell = Nothing
```

`

3. Click SaveAS
4. And Save with .VBS extension

Let me know if any concern.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use another method to delete your temp files, or history.

open notepad.

write the line to delete any file you want into batch file(save notepad to .bat extension)

1.Temporary Internet Files

RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8

2.Cookies

RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2

3.History

RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 1

4.Form Data

RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 16

Passwords

5.RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 32

6.Delete All

RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255

7.Delete All – “Also delete files and settings stored by add-ons”

RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 4351